# Reproduce jQuery UI explode animation with only CSS and HTML?

Tags: css, ios, jquery-ui, cordova

Is it possible to recreate the explode animation from the jQuery UI plugin with only HTML and CSS3?

We would like to include this effect in a PhoneGap app built for iOS devices and prefer a pure CSS solution if possible.

Comment: `explode()` works by cloning the element into several "cells" that are positioned to simulate "slicing". CSS cannot clone elements. Are you willing to alter your markup so the cells are already present and positioned, so you can use CSS transitions to animate them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Impossible. You need to have at least JavaScript support for these kind of effects.

Comment: That's what we assumed, just wanted to check. Thanks! We'll award you the answer if no one else responds soon.